# Web API token - Invalid grant by context.Validate()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

After debugging through the code block, the user pass the user not null test but at Context.Validate() it returns invalid grant

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
            var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            var user = await manager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if(user !=null)
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", user.UserName));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.Email));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

                context.Validated();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the identity inside `Validated()` method. It is also a good idea to set context error if the user is not validated.

So it should look like below:

```
if(user !=null)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", user.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.Email));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("LoggedOn", DateTime.Now.ToString()));

            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
```